# Models not showing up when rendering

Tags: camera

Models not showing up when rendering on blender 2.90 using Cycles or EEVEE. I have restarted my pc, it did not work.
result:

[image]

Comment: Read also: [why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)